# Cannot change input keyboard design in android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("")
```

This code will open Keyboard in android. But How can I change text **color**,***width*** or ***height*** of the input place,background **image**.Is this possible? I found  `TouchScreenKeyboard.area`. But I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html) seems that it uses the OS keyboard so you can't change it.

"area:Returns portion of the screen which is covered by the keyboard."